# VBA group table data by common value in column, for Outlook message

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, outlook, grouping

I have a table of employee data, with each row including their manager's email address. I am writing VBA to send an outlook message to the email addresses from a table column named "Manager Email." I want the email to include data from several other cells in the row. The trick is that I want to group the data for employees that have the same manager into one email, perhaps separated by a new line in the message body.

I figure it will have to do with searching for matching email addresses in the email column, but I am very much a VBA rookie and unsure where to start. I have the email drafting code working fine, but with a separate message for every row. This is it so far:

```
Public Sub Email()
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Audit").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Manager Email").DataBodyRange
Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
For Each cell In rng

    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    objMail.To = Range(cell.Address).Value
    
    objMail.Subject = "(Redacted)"
    
    'for testing, I am just pulling one cell from the row of the address being emailed, two columns away. If there is a way to be specific about the column rather than use Offset, that would be preferable
  
    objMail.Body = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value
  
    objMail.Close (olSave)
    Set objMail = Nothing 
    Next 
    End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have helped many of my clients with similar request. I have one question. do you want to send data of one cell or multiple cells. If it is multiple cells, then most common approach is copy the data of one manager in a new excel file and send that as an attachment.

Comment: It is multiple cells. Is there a way to do this without manually copying the data?

Comment: Oh yes. Nothing is manual here. Create a unique collection of emails and then loop through that collection to copy the data from the source sheet to a "Temp sheet". Once the data is copied, attach that file to the email.. fill rest of the details and send the email. Clear the temp sheet before moving to the next email and then simply repeat the process.

Comment: Hello again, I have been asked to work on a similar project and I want to try your method to send the temp sheet attachment. Do you have an example of what the code would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "searching" for matching addresses, just sort on that column. Start at the top of the data with a "check" variable set to blank. On each row check that variable against the email address on the current row - if it is different then it's time to send the email. If it's the same then just add another row of data to the current email. After each row, set the check variable to the email from that row and move on to the next.

Edit - meant to say if you're not sure of the VBA to sort on a column then use Developer, Record Macro. The resulting code will need to be tidied up but will set you on the right path

Comment: I love this idea, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to add a row of data to a draft email. My code for the email body is simply replacing the message from the row above it rather than adding to it. Any tips?

Comment: I figured out how to combine the string data. Thank you!